# Detect active javascript event handlers

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

How can I detect which javascript event handlers are currently active for the document?  Or a particular element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var ele = $("#web"); // Replace with specified element

ele.click(function(){});
ele.mouseover(function(){});

$.each(ele.data("events"), function(i, e) {     
    alert(i); 
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7HEuW/